# 7zip compressed file cannot be opened because it is invalid in virtual basic

Tags: vb.net, zip, 7zip

I am trying to zip a file using 7zip and the shell method in VB.net
The program succeeds in making a zipped file in the correct directory but when I try to open the file, it says the file is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe locates the 7zip application.

C:\Folder\files.zip is the destination of the zipped files

-t7z - I'm not really sure what this is. I was just informed I needed to use this online.

```
    Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe a -t7z C:\Folder\files.zip C:\Folder\.*stp")
```

Comment: @HansPassant You mean like this: Process.Start("C:\Programme\7-Zip\7za.exe", "a -t7z C:\Folder\files.zip C:\Folder\.*stp")?

Comment: I tried the Process.Start method above but the same thing happened. The zipped file was created but when I try to open the file, it says the file is invalid.

Comment: Replace the .zip extension to .7z and it works. 
Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe a -t7z C:\Folder\files.7z C:\Folder\.*stp")

Comment: For zip it's: Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe a C:\Folder\files.zip C:\Folder\.*stp")

Comment: @Veeke Thanks for responding. I tried this earlier, however the file just becomes a .7z file. Isn't this an uncompressed file?

Comment: I tried this:     Process.Start("C:\Programme\7-Zip\7za.exe", "a -tzip C:\Folder\files.zip C:\Folder\.*dxf"). I can now access the zipped file but there is nothing in it!

Comment: Okay it has to do with the .*dxf. I haven't figured it out yet but I'm closer now. Thanks guys!

Comment: Watch the position of the point : *.dxf (asterix , point, extension)

Comment: Ah thank you that was the problem!